Pivot Filtered on Multiple selections and updates another Pivot Filter to have the same Multiple selections
I have "PivotTable1" with a Filter where the user can pick multiple selections.
I have "PivotTable2", in the same sheet, with the same Filter and the same values.
When the user uses "PivotTable1" and picks one, multiple, or all values in the Filter, I would like to write some VBA that would then automatically update the Filter selection in "PivotTable2" to match what was picked in the Filter for "PivotTable1".
I had written the below VBA which works when just one value is picked, but I'm not sure how to write the VBA when multiple values are picked?
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area").CurrentPage = Range("Area_Picked").Value

Range("Area_Picked").Value is a Named Range I created in the sheet, which is the cell where the Filter is for "PivotTable1"
This is my attempt at creating an answer but I can't quite get the myArray right. If I manually input the myArray values then it works perfectly, but when I try to make myArray the results of the For Each Loop, it fails ("Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField Class").  Even though the Debug.print MS looks exactly the same as the manually input the myArray values.
How can I get the results of MS into the MyArray?
Sub FilterPg()

Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pi_name(1024) As String
Dim MS As String

For Each pi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Area").PivotItems
If pi.Visible = False Then
    pi_name(i) = pi.value
        If MS = "" Then
        MS = """" & pi_name(i) & """"
        Else
        MS = MS & ", " & """" & pi_name(i) & """"
        End If
    i = i + 1
End If
Next pi

Debug.Print MS
'The below is what the Debug.Print MS shows:
'    "Red Zone", "Blue Zone"

Dim myArray() As Variant
'myArray = Array("" & MS & "")
myArray = Array("Red Zone", "Blue Zone")

Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area")
    With pf
        .ClearManualFilter
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
            For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
                .PivotItems(myArray(i)).Visible = False
            Next i
    End With

End Sub



Use Visible to filter the page field

Sub FilterPg()
    Dim pit As PivotItem
    Dim fl As PivotField
    Set fl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area")
    fl.ClearAllFilters
    For Each pit In fl.PivotItems
        pit.Visible = Not IsError(Application.Match(pit.Name, Range("Area_Picked"), 0))
    Next
End Sub


When I run the above code, I get a "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Which line? How do u create the Named Range? Is it exists after refresh?

As soon as I press F8 it shows the error. I think it doesn't like PickerField. I changed your sub as follows, which runs but then fails on the 3rd Next (there are only 3 values in my test data) with the message "unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class":
Sub FilterPg()
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area")
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
pi.Visible = Not IsError(Application.Match(pi.Name, Range("Area_Picked"), 0))
Next
End Sub

It's a typo. Try Dim fl As PivotField. Please validate the Aree_Picked with Debug.Print Range("Area_Picked").Address and make sure at least one item of page field is visible, otherwise it raises 1004 for the last pvt item.

That doesn't produce the Compile error anymore, but it still errors when it gets to the last pivot item ("unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class") because it's trying to untick all of the options in the filter.  I think this Is because the value of Range("Area_Picked") is "(Multiple Items)", and so the loop will never match that and so will always try to untick all of the options.  Maybe my Range("Area_Picked")  should be ignored. What I'm trying to achieve is to filter Pivot Table 2 by the same items that are filtered in Pivot Table 1.
